# Android plugin install Error. operation cannot be completed

Tags: android

I am trying to add plugin android ADT for eclipse.

I've followed the steps given [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing)

But when I am trying to install available softwares its giving error like

> "The Operation cannot be completed. see the details."

in the details the following error is getting displayed.

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: Android Development Tools 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)
>     Missing requirement: Android Development Tools 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534) requires 'org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.6.0' but it could not be found.

I am getting same error even if I downloaded the ADT-16.0.1.zip and given the local archive path.

I am using Eclipse Gelelio.

Answer (score 2):

You are facing an Eclipse bug/issue. You need to following workaround ([also mentioned here](http://code.google.com/intl/es/eclipse/docs/faq.html#wstinstallerror))

> 1. Select Help > Install New Software... Click the link for Available> Software Sites.
> 2. Ensure there is an update site named Galileo. If this is not present, click Add
> 3. Enter `http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo` for the Location
> 4. Now go through the installation steps, Eclipse should download and install the plugin's dependencies.

Comment: This answer does not work. I have galileo and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you use an old version of Eclipse (Galileo) 3.5.x. There is a [requirement](http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html) in Android SDK that you should use Eclipse 3.6 minimum (Helios). So you have to install at first new version of Eclipse.

I faced with the same problem when I was using Ubuntu 10.04 because by default from the repository it installs Eclipse Galileo.